# How to generate JSON array from multiple rows, then return with values of another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to build a query which combines rows of one table into a JSON array, I then want that array to be part of the return.

I know how to do a simple query like

```
SELECT *
FROM public.template 
WHERE id=1
```

And I have worked out how to produce the JSON array that I want

```
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(to_json(fields)))
FROM (
    SELECT id, name, format, data
    FROM public.field
    WHERE template_id = 1
) fields
```

However, I cannot work out how to combine the two, so that the result is a number of fields from public.template with the output of the second query being one of the returned fields.

I am using PostGreSQL 9.6.6

Edit, as requested more information, a definition of field and template tables and a sample of each queries output.

Currently, I have a JSONB row on the template table which I am using to store an array of fields, but I want to move fields to their own table so that I can more easily enforce a schema on them.

Template table contains:

- id
- name
- data
- organisation_id

But I would like to remove data and replace it with the field table which contains:

- id
- name
- format
- data
- template_id

At the moment the output of the first query is:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Test Template",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "data": null,
        "name": "Assigned User",
        "format": "String"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "data": null,
        "name": "Office",
        "format": "String"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "data": null,
        "name": "Department",
        "format": "String"
      }
    ],
    "id_organisation": 1
  }
```

This output is what I would like to recreate using one query and both tables. The second query outputs this, but I do not know how to merge it into a single query:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Assigned User",
    "format": "String",
    "data": null
},{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Office",
    "format": "String",
    "data": null
},{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Department",
    "format": "String",
    "data": null
}]
```

Comment: Could you add an example of input and output rows to get a precise idea of what you want to achieve? As well as the definition of tables `template` and `field`

Comment: I have added more information, let me know if you would like any more. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want multiple rows or a single row? You can always use union all.. I'm quite sure that's not what you're wanting.. but it could be.. I just cannot make heads or tails of what you're asking for,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for poorly phrasing what I was trying to achieve, after hours of Googling I have worked it out and it was a lot more simple than I thought in my ignorance.

```
SELECT id, name, data
FROM public.template, (
    SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(to_json(fields)))
        FROM (
            SELECT id, name, format, data
            FROM public.field
            WHERE template_id = 1
        ) fields
) as data
WHERE id = 1
```

I wanted the result of the subquery to be a column in the ouput rather than compiling the entire output table as a JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you're looking for is json concatenation. You can do that by using the operator `||`. [It's available since PostgreSQL 9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html)

`SELECT to_jsonb(template.*) || jsonb_build_object('data', (SELECT to_jsonb(field) WHERE template_id = templates.id)) FROM template`

Comment: That makes sense, but it throws this error, ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "template"
LINE 1: SELECT to_jsonb(template.*) || jsonb_build_object('data', (S...